# Autowire @Resource from xml and use them for generating list of beans

Tags: java, spring, resources, autowired

Let's assume following situation. In spring xml configuration file there are created beans:

```
<bean id="a" class="com.example.A" />
<bean id="b" class="com.example.B" />
<bean id="c" class="com.example.C" />
<bean id="d" class="com.example.D" >
    <property name="myList" ref="myListBean">
</bean>
```

And Java Configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("path/to/beans.xml")
class JavaConfiguration {
    @Resource
    A a;

    @Resource
    B b;

    @Resource
    D d;

    @Resource
    C c;

    @Bean
    List myListBean(){
        List l = new ArrayList();
        l.add(a);
        l.add(b);
        l.add(c);
        return l;
    }
}
```

Because of @Resource D d is before @Resource C c, Bean 'myListBean' will only contain {a,b,null}. If I switch it and @Resource C is before D then everything is allright. Is there any good practice for avoid that situation, not depends on fields order and prevent from creating bean list with nulls?

Comment: If you have a Configuration class, I would recommend that you define all of your beans there, just because it's cleaner.  You can, however, place the depends-on flag in your bean declaration.

Comment: I am totally aware that example which I showed here is not so good practice. That's look part of legacy code in project I am actually working on. I am wondering if I can do it better so far. We will do refactor in the future but this is bigger case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do exactly what you want.

You can't guarantee that C will be injected by Spring before myListBean if there's no dependency between the two. If you need C to have a correct myListBean, then there should be a dependency.

Comment: That's what I thought.I have just wondered if there is any way to force it. Thanks for answer.